# The Poisson problem $-\Delta u =0$ with $u=g$ on the boundary where $g \in H^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Consider
$$
\begin{align}
-\Delta u =0 & \text{on $\Omega$} \\
u = g & \text{on $\partial\Omega$}
\end{align}
$$
where $g \in H^{\frac{1}{2}}(\partial\Omega)$.

It seems there exists a solution $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ to this problem, but how is existence proved? I am also interested in the estimate
$$|u| \leq C|g|$$
and what the constant depends on. Thanks for any references.

Comment: What is $f$?${}$

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Sorry that's a typo. No $f$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $g\in H^{\frac{1}{2}}(\partial \Omega)$,$\exists v\in H^1(\Omega)$ such that $\gamma_0(v)=g$ where $\gamma_0$ is the trace operator. If you define $w=u-v$ you problem is equivalent to 
$$-\Delta w= \Delta v \ \ \Omega$$
$$w =0 \ \ \ \partial \Omega$$
Notice that $\Delta v\in H^{-1}(\Omega)$ , so using Lax-Milgram theorem (or Riesz in this case) you have that the problem have an unique solution and
$$\|w\|_{H^1}\leq C \|\Delta v\|_{H^{-1}}\leq C'\|v\|_{H^1}$$
so
$$\|u\|_{H^1}\leq \|w\|_{H^1}+\|v\|_{H^1}\leq (C'+1)\|v\|_{H^1}\leq C'' \|g\|_{H^{\frac 1 2 }} $$
the last estimete because of the trace theorem.

Comment: Thank you. Can I not extend $g$ via a different map (not the trace map)? Does it matter??

Comment: @themaker The last estimate is not the boundedness of the trace map (the inequality is the other direction), how did you get it?

Comment: @weasd It is beacause the trace operator is surjective, so by Banach open mapping theorem, it is bounded below.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion:

Say $u$ and $v$ both solve the equation.  Then:

$-\Delta(u-v) = 0$ on $\Omega$ and $(u-v) = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$

Can you now show that $u-v$ must be zero?

Comment: I'm sorry, I stressed the word unqiueness. I meant existence and well-posedness in general.

Comment: Ah.  Different question.  Well, there has to be something on that out there.  This equation has been studied to death, after all.  Don't have anything right at hand myself, though.  Good luck.

Comment: For the homogeneous problem ($g = 0$), expand $f$ in eigen functions of $-\Delta$ and solve. You'll get a solution  $u \in H^{3/2}_0$ and the corresponding estimate. For the problem with $g \ne 0$, you'll need some regularity, e.g. $g \in H^s(\partial \Omega)$ with $s \ge 1/2$.

Comment: @HansEngler Thanks, I changed the problem, So your last sentence is applicable, let me think about it